# How to us Tensorflow boosted tree for image clasification task?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, boost, tree

I was doing image classification using CNN models. I would like to try image classification using decision tree or boosted tree models. I found **Tensorflow** as Boosted tree model, but I'm not able to understand how to give image as an input to the model. If you know how to train image classification using *tf.boosted* tree please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the flatten image feature vector as input. You can use the following code sample that i have tested with mnist Dataset (modified for 2 class). Note that current implementation of tensorflow BoostedTreesClassifier doesn't support pruning for multi class classifier.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

for i in range(len(y_train)):
    if y_train[i] is not 0:
        y_train[i] = 1

for i in range(len(y_test)):
    if y_test[i] is not 0:
        y_test[i] = 1

NUM_FEATURES = 28*28

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train.reshape(-1,NUM_FEATURES)}, y_train, batch_size=128, num_epochs=5, shuffle=True)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_test.reshape(-1,NUM_FEATURES)}, y_test, batch_size=128, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

features = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=(NUM_FEATURES,))]

est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(features, n_batches_per_layer=1)
est.train(train_input_fn)
results = est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
print('Accuracy : ', results['accuracy'])
```